# IDB file Maximum kb limit

Tags: mysql, innodb, table

I'm new in handling MySQL database, I made a tracking system I using the MySQL database incorporated on the xampp package as a database. Everything is running smoothly, however upon reaching 90,112 kb on the idb file of one of the tables from the database, it crashed and it cannot be used anymore. I cannot start the server due to the table.
It shows the following error.

> [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>    [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>    [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

As a temporary action I deleted the table a made a new one with the same structure and imported all the data that I have extracted before. Now it seems that it will happen again as the idb file of the table is reaching 90,112 kb and the system is slowing down again. Is there a limit on the table memory? Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?  Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need the mysql version and the mysql error log contents to start diagnosing this error. Also recommend not deleting and moving innodb files around in the mean time.

Comment: [Limits on Table Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-size-limit.html), [Limits on InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html). 90 Mb is NOT MySQL limitation.

Comment: You did not run out of disk space on any filesystem partition, did you?